# Sending the same messages to multiple users at the same time in Instagram

Tags: automation, instagram-api

I am trying to implement the program for sending the same direct messages to multiple users in Instagram. I looked through the official Meta API and none of it provided what I am looking for. It is more like responding to the users who first reached me. I want vice versa. I want to initiate conversations with many users. Are there any possible ways?

Here is what I came up with as solutions and its limitations

1. web scraping : slow
2. the manual web socket connection : but is this possible?

And I have no ideas...

Comment: I'm pretty sure they intentionally don't want you to be able to write spam bots.

Comment: Details are missing. Which account is sending out messages? Is it a private, public, creator or business account? Had the account contacted the recipients before? Are they followers of your account? Don't spam via Instagram DM.

Comment: I just wanted to smooth out the process to contact the popular creators for some contracts. so it would be public and creator accounts. not for the purpose of spams.

Comment: Copy & paste, and send to the recipients one by one is your solution.

Comment: well no option. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the unofficial instagram API. https://github.com/subzeroid/instagrapi

this is not the official API and built from reverse engineering.

It is not stable but worth trying